# Parsing xml using XDocument - Deserialization

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Actions>
    <add order-id="1" symbol="ABC" price="5" quantity="200" />
    <add order-id="2" symbol="123" price="15" quantity="100" />
    <add order-id="3" symbol="ABC" price="5" quantity="300" />
    <add order-id="4" symbol="ABC" price="7" quantity="150" />
    <edit order-id="1" price="7" quantity="200" />
    <remove order-id="4" />
    <add order-id="5" symbol="123" price="17" quantity="300" />
    <add order-id="6" symbol="123" price="12" quantity="150" />
    <edit order-id="3" price="7" quantity="200" />
    <remove order-id="5" />
</Actions>
```

I need to parse this using linq into the following object structure:

```
 internal class OrderAction
    {
        private readonly Action action;
        private readonly Order order;
        public Action Action { get { return action; }}
        public Order Order { get { return order; }}

        public OrderAction(Action action,Order order)
        {
            this.action = action;
            this.order = order;
        }
    }
```

where an action is  `public enum Action { ADD, REMOVE, EDIT }`

an order is as follows:

```
class Order
    {
        public Order(long orderId, String symbol, int price, int quantity)
        {
            this.orderId = orderId;
            this.symbol = symbol;
            this.price = price;
            this.quantity = quantity;
        }

        public long orderId { get; private set; }
        public String symbol { get; private set; }
        public int price { get; private set; }
        public int quantity { get; private set; }
}
```

I need to load the xml into an xdocument and find all the IEnumerable of orderactions in the file. How can i do this, without resorting into serialization attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What should the values of the missing `Order` properties be in case of "edit and "remove"? I assumed the default values for `string` and `int`...

This would be the LINQ statement (assuming that your `XDocument` is called `doc`):

```
var result = doc
    .Root
    .Elements()
    .Select(elem => new OrderAction
            (
                (Action)Enum.Parse(typeof(Action), elem.Name.LocalName.ToUpper()),
                new Order
                (
                    elem.Attributes("order-id").Select(x => long.Parse(x.Value)).FirstOrDefault(),
                    elem.Attributes("symbol").Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                    elem.Attributes("price").Select(x => int.Parse(x.Value)).FirstOrDefault(),
                    elem.Attributes("quantity").Select(x => int.Parse(x.Value)).FirstOrDefault()
                )
            ));
```

Comment: what's Root? is this compiling?

Comment: `Root` is a property of `XDocument` (returns root `XElement`)... yes, compiling and running successfully

Comment: i see... you can shorten that by opening the document with XElement

Answer (score 0):

here's my best shot

```
     XElement doc = XElement.Load("d:\\tst.xml");

     List<OrderAction> lst = doc.Elements().Select(x =>
       new OrderAction(
          (Action)
          Enum.Parse(typeof (Action),
                     x.Name.ToString().ToUpper()),
          new Order(
             long.Parse(x.Attribute("order-id").Value),
             x.Attribute("symbol") != null ? x.Attribute("symbol").Value : "",
             x.Attribute("price") != null ? int.Parse(x.Attribute("price").Value) : 0,
             x.Attribute("quantity") != null ? int.Parse(x.Attribute("quantity").Value): 0))
        ).ToList();
```

it took me a while... i'm not used to that big of linq parse

Comment: shouldn't this crash for edit/remove tag since `Attribute` will return `null`??? you are also asking for the wrong attributes...

Comment: @olydis lemme fix that

Comment: @olydis tnx, did not noticed that